# Как через IdHTTP получить все фото со страницы?

Tags: c++builder, c++

Можно ли через IdHTTP как-нибудь получить все фото со страницы: допустим, включаем программу, пишем в Edit1 http:\rambler.ru, нажимаем получить и пошло получение всех картинок... И ещё в какой компонент можно получить все изображения?

Comment: Придумайте осмысленное название, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

в общем алгоритм такой:

Получаете html код страницы при помощи IDHTTP;

Парсите все ссылки на картинки из этого кода в какой ни будь список(Stringlist, Listbox, Memo...);

[как закачать файл из интернета](http://codup.blogspot.com/2011/05/blog-post.html)

Переходите по ссылке выше, и поочередно закачиваете все эти изображения.